# Dart UnitTest: orderedEquals combined with closeTo

Tags: dart

As I try to get familiar with dart unit tests, I encountered the following problem,

I have a list of nums which I would like to compare to a expected list of nums. These values MAY be "doubles" and therefor a comparison with closeTo would be necessary.

is it possible to combine those two matchers somehow or do I need to write my own or is there any matcher I skipped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a specific matcher which combines the functionality of both matchers to compare two separate iterables. However, you can easily write a test to iterate over both collections and check that the value is closeTo expected. Remember you can have more than one `expect()` statement per test.

So your test could look something like this:

```dart
test('List is close', () {
    var expectedList = [1, 3, 56, 892, 919];
    List<num> myVals = someFunction();

    var len = expectedList.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      expect(myVals[i], closeTo(expectedList[i], 0.005));
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, did it the way you described, but opened a bug/feature request for the dart team.  Added list-length expectation too